# Groovy - extensions structure

Tags: groovy

I'd like to extend `String`'s `asType` method to handle `LocalDateTime`. I know how to override this method, however I've no idea where should I put it in project structure to work globally - for all strings in my project. Is it enough to put such *extension* wherever in the classpath? I know that there's a special convention for extensions (META-INF/services), how does it work for method overriding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All documentation regarding this topic can be found [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/core-metaprogramming.html#_extension_modules). And [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/core-metaprogramming.html#module-descriptor) exactly the relevant part can be found.

**Module extension and module descriptor**

> For Groovy to be able to load your extension methods, you must declare
>   your extension helper classes. You must create a file named
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule into the META-INF/services
>   directory:
>
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule moduleName=Test module for
>   specifications moduleVersion=1.0-test
>   extensionClasses=support.MaxRetriesExtension
>   staticExtensionClasses=support.StaticStringExtension The module
>   descriptor requires 4 keys:
>
> moduleName : the name of your module
>
> moduleVersion: the version of your module. Note that version number is
>   only used to check that you don’t load the same module in two
>   different versions.
>
> extensionClasses: the list of extension helper classes for instance
>   methods. You can provide several classes, given that they are comma
>   separated.
>
> staticExtensionClasses: the list of extension helper classes for
>   static methods. You can provide several classes, given that they are
>   comma separated.
>
> Note that it is not required for a module to define both static
>   helpers and instance helpers, and that you may add several classes to
>   a single module. You can also extend different classes in a single
>   module without problem. It is even possible to use different classes
>   in a single extension class, but it is recommended to group extension
>   methods into classes by feature set.

**Module extension and classpath**

> It’s worth noting that you can’t use an extension which is compiled at
>   the same time as code using it. That means that to use an extension,
>   it has to be available on classpath, as compiled classes, before the
>   code using it gets compiled. Usually, this means that you can’t have
>   the test classes in the same source unit as the extension class
>   itself. Since in general, test sources are separated from normal
>   sources and executed in another step of the build, this is not an
>   issue.